# An Excel file prevents me to do interactive rebase in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: excel, git, intellij-idea, binaryfiles, rebase

I face a merge conflict when I would like to rebase the `develop` branch against my `feature` branch. I use IntelliJ Idea to execute individual Git commands. Let's say I have 3 pushed commits and I want to squash and rebase them using `--interactive` mode.

[image]

I select all three commits, I select `squash`, do some rewording, and hit `Rebase`.

[image]

The process fails and an Excel file that appears in the Git panel among *Changes* and on the diff panel, says the contents are the same. I can only abort or retry the rebase, but continuing doesn't make sense as the change always prevents me to continue.

[image]

Here is the console output:

```
12:50:42.385: [myapplication] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false -c core.commentChar= rebase --interactive develop
Rebasing (1/2)
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    excel-file.xlsx
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
hint: Could not execute the todo command
hint: 
hint:     fixup 37d1fc57dff9c7e9a312c88cf78c176cb71dbb47 CommitMessageIsHere
hint: 
hint: It has been rescheduled; To edit the command before continuing, please
hint: edit the todo list first:
hint: 
hint:     git rebase --edit-todo
hint:     git rebase --continue
Could not apply 37d1fc5... CommitMessageIsHere
```

Is there a trick to overcome this obstacle? Is possible to somehow *force* ignoring and skipping such merge conflict?

Comment: Do you have a view of `git`'s output when it tries to run `git rebase` ? more specifically : it it stops because of a conflict, what kind of conflict is it ?

Comment: @LeGEC: I have added the console output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started your rebase with un untracked copy of `excel-file.xlsx`, and when `git` met a commit which included the action "create a new `excel-file.xlsx` file", he stopped.

You have to somehow put aside this untracked version before proceeding.

---

The simplest way is:

- rename that file on disk:

  ```
  mv excel-file.xlsx excel-file.xlsx.tmp
  ```
- run `git rebase --continue`:
  either IntelliJ has a button which looks like "proceed with the rebase", or you can run this command from the command line,
- once the rebase is complete:
  you can compare the contents of both files, and decide what the correct action is -- update the tracked version, delete the tmp file ...